# Pancake Glutton - the one one who ate the least

Tags: c++

I'm taking the cplusplus.com beginner exercises to use what I'm learning in c++. I came up with the Pancake Glutton exercise.

---

**Pancake Glutton**

Requires:
variables, data types, and numerical operators
basic input/output
logic (if statements, switch statements)
loops (for, while, do-while)
arrays

Write a program that asks the user to enter the number of pancakes eaten for breakfast by 10 different people (Person 1, Person 2, ..., Person 10)
Once the data has been entered the program must analyze the data and output which person ate the most pancakes for breakfast.

★ Modify the program so that it also outputs which person ate the least number of pancakes for breakfast.

★★★★ Modify the program so that it outputs a list in order of number of pancakes eaten of all 10 people.

---

My program solves this problem, yet I made so the amount of people is inserted by the user. My problem is when the program looks for the person that ate the *least* amount of pancakes, my program crashes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int people,i,maxi=0,cakes, mini=0;
string name,glutton,nibbler;

int main()
{
    //Ask user the amount of people that have eaten pancakes
    cout<<"How many people have eaten pancakes? \n";
    cin>>people;

    //Assign the names of each person that ate pancakes
    string names[people];
    for(i=0;i<people;i++){
        cout<<"Name? ";
        cin>>name;
        names[i]=name;
    }

    cout<<endl;

    //Ask how many pancakes each person has eaten
    int nums[people];
    for(i=0;i<people;i++){
        cout<<"How many pancakes did "<<names[i]<<" eat?"<<endl;
        cin>>cakes;
        nums[i]=cakes;
    }

    cout<<endl;

    //Compare to take the person that ate the most
    for(i=0;i<people;i++){
        if(nums[i]>maxi){
            maxi=nums[i];
            glutton=names[i];
        }
    }

    mini=maxi;
    /*I assigned the value of max to mini to make starting
    *point of comparison to look for the one that ate the
    *least
    */

    //Compare for the person that ate the least
    /**This is what makes my program explode, and I don't know why*/
    for(i=0;i<people;i--){
        if(nums[i]<mini){
            mini=nums[i];
            nibbler=names[i];
        }
    }

    cout<<glutton<<" ate the most"<<endl;
    cout<<nibbler<<" ate the least"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int people...string names[people];` -- `int nums[people];` -- This is not valid C++.  In C++, arrays are declared using a compile-time constant to denote the number of entries in the array, not a variable such as `int people`.  Variable arrays are done in C++ by using `std::vector`.

Comment: `for(i=0;i<people;i--)` this will never terminate.

Comment: Use your debugger to step through the code to see where it goes wrong.  See also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert

Comment: @MikeHarris Have you considered an integer underflow? Your statement will not be applicable to those (probably widely spread) environments where an integer underflow results in the highest possible value.

Comment: @Yunnosch you are correct, of course. The loop will terminate when the integer wraps. The bigger problem is that after the first iteration, the value of `i` will be -1, which will cause problems with the `nums[i]` dereference. Likely the program will crash before integer overflow.

Comment: You're going to want to avoid declaring arbitrary global variables and instead move these local to the function in which they are used. Additionally, avoid `using namespace std` as this can create conflicts with your own code. The `std::` prefix is there for a reason. Instead of two different arrays you should steer towards a solution that uses a struct that combines name and number, then use that when gathering data. You should also use `std::vector` and `push_back` instead of fixed length arrays.

Answer (score -1):

Basically I found I could just use the positions in the arrays to make the code shorter, easier to understand and obviously faster. I know with this kind of program memory matters nothing, yet I should get the habit from the start.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int people,i,glutton=0,cakes,nibbler=0;
string name;

int main()
{
    //Ask user the amount of people that have eaten pancakes
    cout<<"How many people have eaten pancakes? \n";
    cin>>people;

    //Assign the names of each person that ate pancakes
    string names[people];
    for(i=0;i<people;i++){
        cout<<"Name? ";
        cin>>name;
        names[i]=name;
    }

    cout<<endl;

    //Ask how many pancakes each person has eaten
    int nums[people];
    for(i=0;i<people;i++){
        cout<<"How many pancakes did "<<names[i]<<" eat?"<<endl;
        cin>>cakes;
        nums[i]=cakes;
    }

    cout<<endl;

    //Compare to take the person that ate the most and the least

    for(i=1;i<people;i++){
        if(nums[i]>nums[glutton]){
            glutton=i;
        }
        if(nums[i]<nums[nibbler]){
            nibbler=i;
        }
    }

    cout<<names[glutton]<<" ate the most"<<endl;
    cout<<names[nibbler]<<" ate the least"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's tools in the Standard Library to [find the minimal and maximal values](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) in a container. Using that would avoid having to write such primitive, low-level code. Always look for methods like this before banging together your own.

Comment: Downvoting since this is not C++ (see my comment above).  Others will read this that are using Visual Studio or an ANSI compliant compiler, will try to run it, and get blasted with compiler errors.